# How do I keep original pandas dataframe values while using df.astype() ? I need to raise a value error for below example

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 
'B': [1, 2.5, 3, 4, 5], 
'C': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno'] })

col_type = {'A':str, 'B':int, 'C':str}

df = df.astype(col_type)
df

Output is:  
    A   B   C
0   a   1   abc
1   b   2   def
2   c   3   ghi
3   d   4   jkl
4   e   5   mno
```

But I want to raise a value error at index 1 for column B. I don't need the integer value. I want to do it automatically( Like loop through all columns)

Comment: "keep original pandas dataframe values " if you want this then why are you converting?

Comment: I want to enforce column data types. And if any column has incorrect value then I want to raise an error

Answer (score 0):

Panda's built `.astype()` in doesn't appear to have a 'safe casting' method as you want.

In numpy you can use
`np.ndarray.astype(preferred_type, casting='safe')`

So unfortunately I don't have a pretty solution for you but I would do something like

```
coltypes = [str,int,str]
colnames = ['a','b','c']
data_for_df =  [df.values[:,i].astype(coltypes[i], casting='safe') for i in range(len(df))]
df = pd.DataFrame(data_for_df,columns=colnames)
```

Someone might be able to give a better answer than me :)

Comment: casting option doesn't tell the column name where issue is.  I need to do this for multiple columns. So that I can validate all columns.

Comment: You  could try de-constructing the list comprehension into a for loop and then throwing the error where it comes up

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control that some columns of floating point values only contain integers, you can simply examine the difference between the original column(s) and the same one(s) after int conversion:

```
(df['B'] - df['B'].astype('int')) == 0
```

gives following Series:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
Name: B, dtype: bool
```

From there, you can raise an exception

```
tmp = (df['B'] - df['B'].astype('int')) == 0
if not tmp.all():
    raise TypeError("Non int value at "+ ', '.join(df[(df['B'] - df['B'].astype('int')) != 0]
                     .index.astype(str)))
```

With the sample data, it gives as expected:

```
TypeError: Non int value at 1
```